# Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation when running `tns platform add android`

Tags: android, nativescript

I am following an official NativeScript [tutorial](http://docs.nativescript.org/getting-started) and having a problem configuring my OS X environment for android development.

When running `tns platform add android` I receive the following error:

> Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 21 or later.

The `tns doctor` command also returns warnings on android-sdk issues:

> Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to
>   build for Android, install Android SDK 21 or later. Run `$ android` to
>   manage your Android SDK versions. You need to have the Android SDK
>   Build-tools installed on your system. You have to install version 22.
>   Run "android" from your command-line to install required Android Build
>   Tools. You need to have the latest Android Support Repository
>   installed on your system. Run `$ android`  to manage the Android
>   Support Repository.

My android-sdk installation looks like this:

[image: Android-SDK-installations]

My .bash_profile also includes the followings:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.4/"

export PATH="$PATH:~/npm-global/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.4/tools:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.4/platform-tools"
```

Should I go further and try setting system-wide environment variables - not just for the .bash_profile? Also, it is possible that I missed something from the setup process...

Any tip on how I could debug this situation (commands, config files etc.) would be great, thank you!

Comment: I am in the same situation. I'll update here once I fix this issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Alright, so you need to make sure of following:

- Make sure you have API 22 installed.
- Make sure you you have Android SDK Build Tools 22.x.x installed. (Yes,
  specifically 22.x.x)
- Make sure you have Android support repository installed. (You can
  find it under Extras section in Android SDK Manager)

Once you have performed steps mentioned above, run `tns doctor` again and you should see `No issues were detected` message.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the *tns* error message was confusing because it was saying: `To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 21 or later` but then it also asks specifically for the `version 22 SDK` and this, I have ignored because I had a newer (v24) version already installed. Once I have installed SDK 22 and the Support Repository from the Extras, it works fine.

Comment: I've followed these instructions and i keep getting the same message i have API 22 installed build-tools 22.0.1 installed and support repository 24 installed...

Comment: oops. i was missing the android_home

Comment: I had the same problem, but it was related to the "build-tools" not showing in the SDK Manager.  I was following the tutorial instructions for NativeScript, specifically using chocolatey to get "android-sdk" was my issue.  I decided to download the sdk via Android Studio and that solved the problem.

Comment: HOW?! All of these answers only list other problems but not the actual steps to solve them. As someone with no familiarity with Android Studio I cannot find `Extras` in any of the menus, I can't find an Android SDK Manager application to run or a menu item to click. Running `$ android` returns `The "android" command is deprecated.`

Comment: Well, this answer does not cover basic Android tutorial.

Comment: Have in mind that this could happen with other versions, for example with "... build for Android, install Android SDK 27 or later." and you just need to install the next version, in the example the "28". Although it may be confusing by the "... or later", you need the next version. I don't really know why.

Answer (score 8):

This is because of `sudo`. The root user has no `ANDROID_HOME` set.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11007356)

Comment: Although my English sucks, but it is the correct answer, I was through the actual testing.

Comment: running sudo echo $ANDROID_HOME still gives the location of my sdk. this doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 7):

For Windows User:

1. Run 'android update sdk' from command line
2. Select Android 5.1.1(API22)
3. Select Tools folder
4. Select Extras and click on Install.

ps:- adding this answer, so that if any one land on this page can see it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the ANDROID_HOME is ok
2. Install the API 22 + ion the Extras > Android Support Repository
3. Run the following

   - tns platform remove android
   - tns platform add android@next
4. Run

   tns run android

then it should be OK

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem installing `Android Support Repository` from `Extras`.

Answer (score 1):

updating SDK  in `AndroidStudio >> Preferences`would help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

on my windows 10 machine I had to open file explorer right click on this pc and go to properties on the left hand side I had to go to advanced settings. At the bottom I click environment variables then on the android_home variable I clicked edit then pointed it to this path on my machine where the sdk was installed 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

This answer is on a Linux, not OSX, platform. However, since this is the SO that appears most often for the listed error, I'll share a recent fix that worked for me.

If you have done all of the above and are still getting the error, try this solution.

I am using NativeScript 8.0.2.

You will know that ANDROID_HOME and Java are configured correctly if you can run the command `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list`. If that **fails**, then first check that your Java is compatible (I had to add OpenJDK 8 and change my PATH with `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0/"`)

In **Android Studio**, add a previous build tool version. Go to your SDK Manager > SDK Tools, tick the bottom box "Show package details", and add a previous version. In my case, *31.0.0* was the latest, and I added *30.0.3*. Now run `ns doctor android` again and everything should pass.

Seems *31.0.0* is not yet properly recognised by Native Script.

Answer (score 0):

I always got the error "✖ Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 28 or later. "

I actually had to go to the android studio settings and install the exact SDK 28 before this error went away.
[Android Settings Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFcoC.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is an updated answer, I also had the same issue:

[image: ns doctor android in Terminal on Windows 11]

Like all the previous pictures above, I had to install the SDK platforms, using the SDK Manager. From the main screen of Android Studio, click More Actions and choose SDK Manager. Before that I had to add the platform-tools to my PATH in Windows

> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

That fixed my issue and the [docs for setup are here](https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html).

[image]