# nativescript run failed - build-tools not installed

Tags: android, linux, facebook-android-sdk, nativescript

I just start to learn nativescript and i made a nativescript project,
when i want to run it via `tns run android --emulator` it says :

```
You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools 
installed on your system. You have to install version 23
```

tns doctors command :

```
You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You have to install version 23.
Run android from your command-line to install required Android Build Tools.

You need to have Android SDK 22 or later and the latest Local Maven repository for Support Libraries installed on your system.
Run $ android  to manage the Local Maven repository for Support Libraries.
```

my android sdk image
[image]

I also follow instruction #2 answer in this topic : [Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation when running `tns platform add android`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723748/cannot-find-a-compatible-android-sdk-for-compilation-when-running-tns-platform)

my android_home in .bashrc :

```
#AndroidDev PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=~/android-sdk-linux/
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran this and it was resolved.

```
android update sdk --filter tools,platform-tools,android-23,build-tools-23.0.2,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository,extra-android-support --all --no-ui
```

Comment: how do you run that on windows ? i tried without successs

Comment: The "android" command is deprecated. For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio. For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

Answer (score 0):

I can't really test it on Linux enviroment but I think this topic is related to your issues - [Android build failing with build.xml:479: SDK does not have any Build Tools installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631693/android-build-failing-with-build-xml479-sdk-does-not-have-any-build-tools-inst)

In two words (as suggested in the topic) you can try

```
android update sdk -u
```

and then assure that you have build-tools installed in Android SDK manager.
The latest linux SDK tools version is 24.4.1

Comment: The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager